# Reuse tramp connection details to start putty session

Tags: tramp, process, ssh

I often connect to remote servers using tramp to do some work, however sometimes after editing files I need to connect using PuTTY in order to do some specific task.

At the moment I open up PuTTY, and type the user and server names in. It seems to me that tramp already has that information and I should be able to run an Emacs command that extracts tramp connection details for the current buffer and runs PuTTY for me. I can't work out how to get this information, though.

Note: I can't just run commands over the tramp connection (eg, with <kbd>M-!</kbd>) as it may require variables set up in the .profile.

Comment: Have you tried executing M-x shell and opening a shell on the remote host inside emacs?

Answer (score 1):

You might try it the other way. Create a PuTTY session with all information you need (user name, host name, etc). You could use this PuTTY session with `"/plinkx:sessionname:"` then. You could even share the connection between Emacs/Tramp and the native PuTTY connection.

Comment: I don't think I've described what I'm trying to do very well. I'm really lazy and can't be bothered retyping the username and servername (or session name) when I run PuTTY, so I was wondering if there's a simple way of getting that from tramp. I guess I could just extract it using a regexp. (Thanks for all your work on tramp, btw, it's fantastic!)

Comment: In this case, try `(file-remote-p default-directory 'user)` and `(file-remote-p default-directory 'host)`.